# How do I use regex to set text lowercase?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have my code below:

```
var fileContent = reader.result;

for (var index = 0; index < fileContent.length; index++) {
  fileContent[index] = fileContent[index].replace(/(^|(?<=\|))(TRUE|FALSE|True|False)(\||$)/g, function(upperCase) {
                            return upperCase.toLowerCase();
                          });
                        }
```

the value of filecontent is the following:

```
12435|#CANON#DEVICE#|#50#|Machine Detail|Details|SampleRow|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|TRUE
```

I wanna manipulate the TRUE and FALSE value. If they're in uppercase, I want to make it lowercase. Any idea how I can do it? thank you. Above code isnt working.

Comment: I think your pattern works, but lookbehinds are not widely supported. It works in the latest versions of chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/4b8c7z50/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following

```
fileContent[index].split('|').map(function(item) {
   if (item.match(/^(TRUE|FALSE)$/)( {
       return item.toLowerCase();
   }
   return item;
}).join('|');
```

this should work when you don't have text like `foo|"xx|xx"|bar`.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution for this is to provide a function to `string.replace`

In the code bellow:

our regex is `/(true|false)/gi`, it will match `true` or `false` strings and capture it, it also has the flags `/g` which means it will find all matches and `/i` which ignore case.

We then have the replacer function `(_, p1) => p1.toLowerCase()` which will ignore the first argument, we only want the result of the capture group 1, or `p1`, we then make it lowercase and return it.

```js
fileContent.replace(/(true|false)/gi, (_, p1) => p1.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your regex. The check for the closing boundary `(\||$)` will match the `|` itself as well. You want to use a look-ahead there. Just as you did for the starting boundary `(^|(?<=\|))` with a look-behind.

```
/(^|(?<=\|))(TRUE|FALSE|True|False)((?=\|)|$)/g
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace and it's callback

```
(^|\|)(TRUE|FALSE)(?=\||$)
```

[image]

```js
let str = `12435|#CANON#DEVICE#|#50#|Machine Detail|Details|SampleRow|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|FALSE|TRUE`

let replacer = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/(^|\|)(TRUE|FALSE)(?=\||$)/g, (m, g1, g2) => `${g1}${g2.toLowerCase()}`)
}

console.log(replacer(str))
```